# Override a ModelForm field value set using ModelForm(instance=some_instance)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following models—

```
class Book(Model):
 title = CharField(max_length=100)
 author = ForeignKey('Author')

class Author(models.Model):
 name = CharField(max_length=100)
```

And have a standard `ModelForm` to `Book`.

In the form, `author` is a `ModelChoiceField`, and is rendered as a `<select>`. I'd like it to be text field where you can input the author's name—`Author.name`.

If there's already an author with that name, the saved model uses that in its foreign key, otherwise an author with that name is created (and used in its foreign key)—in effect, `Author.get_or_create(name=posted_name_value)`.

I've found that the simplest way is to override the field as a `CharField`, like so—

```
class BookForm(ModelForm):

 author = CharField()

 class Meta:
  model = Book
```

Although with that I can add custom `clean` logic that does what I want, I can't do the same with the pre-populated value when using `BookForm(instance=some_book_object)`—the `CharField` gets set to the `Author`'s `pk`, not its name.

I've tried to do this but I can't seem to find out how. I've tried overriding things in `BookForm.__init__` to no avail.

**How can I override a fields' value set when using `instance` with a `ModelForm`?**

Answer (score 0):

You could override the field content by this:

```
form = BookForm(instance=instance, initial={'name': instance.author.name})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add `author` to the ModelForm meta's `exclude`, then have a form field called `author_name` that you populate using `initial`, and save into the model in the view's `form_valid` method (assuming you are using generic form view classes).