# Enforcing values for some fields when using ModelForm

Tags: database, django, security, modelform

I have a Django app where users submit orders for payment. Clearly, security is important. I want to minimise the amount of code that I have to write, to avoid introducing any security holes, and ease maintenance.

The model is simple:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    paid = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
```

I'm using a [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) to create instances of Order:

```
class OrderView(CreateView):
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm
```

I want to enforce values for certain fields in those instances. For example, I want the instance `user` field set to the current logged-in user. I don't want any possibility that the user can change the value of this field, so I don't want it to appear in the form at all. Therefore I use a custom [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) to remove these fields from the form:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        # For security, we control exactly which fields are placed
        # in the form, rather than excluding some:
        fields = ('items',)
```

Now I want the newly created Order instances to have the `user` field set to the current logged-in user. I can't find any documentation about what is the *best* way to do this.

**(A)** I can override the form's `save()` method to modify the object before saving, but it feels like this code doesn't belong in the form, which doesn't know anything about the `user` field. I also don't have access to the `request` here, which I'd need to determine the current user. But it might look like this:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(OrderForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.user = get_request_magic().user
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```

**(B)** I can [override the view's `form_valid` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239976) to save the object with commit=False, like a class-based version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466768). But I can't call the superclass method directly, because it saves the object with no way to disable commit, so I have to manually skip a generation of `form_valid` which is nasty. Apart from that complaint, this does look like the best way I've found so far:

```
class OrderView(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

**(C)** I could write a replacement for `CreateView` that adds a hook to allow objects to be changed before saving them. But that feels like more boilerplate and duplication.

**(D)** I can't [provide an `initial` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988548), because there's no form field to put it in, so it will be ignored.

Any other ideas? If (B) the best option, is there any way around the hacky way of manually specifying which superclass' `form_valid` method I want to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django user *Charettes* [answered the question](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19553#comment:2) for me:

> You can achieve this by overriding form_valid:

```
class OrderCreateViewMixin(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = request.user
        return super(OrderCreateViewMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Which pointed me towards the [right part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user):

```
class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = AuthorForm
    model = Author

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(AuthorCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

This is definitely the simplest and cleanest answer I've found so far. It doesn't require modifying the form in any way, although it does directly access its `instance` member which is a bit ugly. However, at least it's officially documented, so it's unlikely to break.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple approaches to this. I would do this:

Create a constructor in your form which takes the request:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
```

When creating your form for POST processing, instantiate it as follows:

```
form = OrderForm(data=request.POST, request=request)
```

Now, in your save() method, you have access to the user on the request by referencing `self.request.user` and can set it accordingly on your model.

Comment: Unfortunately the last part doesn't work. In the `ModelForm` `save()` method, we do now have access to `request`, but not to the new instance! That's created by the `save_instance` function (not method), which calls the `construct_instance` function (not method), so I have to override both of these as well, and it gets ugly again.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've gone about handling this situation with CBVs, is to pass in an unsaved instance of the model to the form.  This is how I've done it:

```
class OrderView(CreateView):
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        self.object = Order(user=self.request.user)
        return super(OrderView, self).get_form_kwargs()
```

Both `CreateView` and `UpdateView` will add `instance` to the form kwargs, setting it to the value of `self.object`.

The only other way, besides what you've already mentioned, is to construct your view class from the same elements that `CreateView` does, and then change the get and post methods to populate `self.object` there.  I've done that when I have needed *a lot* of create views in my project:

```
class OrderView(SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, ModelFormMixin, ProcessFormView):
    template_name_suffix = '_form'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = Order(user=request.user)
        return super(OrderView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = Order(user=request.user)
        return super(OrderView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here is a more generalized version to be reused: https://gist.github.com/4439975

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately it requires poking into the undocumented `object` property of `CreateView`, which could change in future and break this code.